# How to implement dynamic feature in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

How to implement this behavior in .NET 3.5, where there is no `dynamic` keyword.

```
Guid CLSID_ShellApplication = new Guid("13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000");
Type shellApplicationType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_ShellApplication, true);
dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(shellApplicationType);
dynamic windows = shellApplication.Windows();

for (int i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++)
    windows.Item(i).Refresh();
```

I tried using

```
MethodInfo windowsMethod = shellApplicationType.GetMethod("Windows");
```

but `GetMethod` returns `null`.

Comment: try out var instead of dynamic might work for you..

Comment: @PranayRana No, it'll still be an object.

Comment: You need to add BindingFlags to your method call, so it'll know which type of method to look for. For instance, BindingFlags.Public and BindingFlags.Instance.

Comment: You can do it through reflection, but it will be most longer piece of code. To give you solution, i need to see what is your target type.

Comment: CreateInstance in code snippet above returns object of type System._ComObject

Comment: Pranay Rana: var will not work as var is implicit typed. --> the compiler translates that to explicit, but you just have to write less.

Comment: is the type in shellApplicationType correct when you look at it with the debugger?

Comment: yes, it's type is System._ComObject.

Comment: BindingFlags.Public and BindingFlags.Instance don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is dynamic behaviour in .NET < 4.0, you can go DLR straight
Check this site http://dlr.codeplex.com/
And also you can take a look at this video. The guy behind IronPython shows how to implement a DLR binder for office (which uses COM)
http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/tl10